# Change Inertia tag to InertiaJS

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [inertia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inertia) tag is currently reserved for the [InertiaJS library](https://inertiajs.com/). This can be a cause of confusion and will make the tag messy, since most people who tag their post with [inertia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inertia) do so with the intent of showing that their question is related to [the law of motion in physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia).

This just creates extra work for the review queue, since as soon as someone does this it needs to be removed seeing as it's not related to the InertiaJS library.

I propose we add a new tag ([inertiajs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inertiajs)) and retag InertiaJS posts that currently have the [inertia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inertia) to [inertiajs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inertiajs).

Comment: How many of those 22 questions are now tagged incorrectly?

Comment: I think two: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60760357/1364007), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60743393/1364007). I think all the InertiaJS questions are either [also tagged with laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inertia+laravel) or [with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inertia+reactjs).

Comment: @WaiHaLee that's what I got as well.

Comment: I've not been involved in tag cleanups much (if at all), but I think it might be easier to have the tag removed from the two 'bad' questions, then have the tag renamed to inertiajs (or similar).

Comment: @WaiHaLee yeah, if it is tagged wrong now and you have full edit privileges removing tags for just two questions is fine. It only becomes a problem if you retag 100 questions (and even worse without full edit privileges).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wai Ha Lee removed the [inertia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inertia) tag from the two questions that were not about the JavaScript library.

I have now renamed the [inertia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inertia) tag to [inertiajs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inertiajs) to hopefully avoid this confusion in the future.

Comment: It seems that `inertia` is still a synonym for `inertiajs` from what I can see. This should be removed, right?

Comment: @Linus I intentionally made it a synonym. This will ensure that no bookmarks are broken. If someone types "inertia" into the tag box, it will automatically be replaced with "inertiajs", which will hopefully clue them into the fact that the tag is not about the general physics concept.